# Can I use ffmpeg to output jpgs to a numpy array in python without writing the files to disk etc?

Tags: python, numpy, ffmpeg

I have to read thousands of images in memory.This has to be done.When i extract frames using ffmpeg from a video,the disk space for the 14400 files =92MB and are in JPG format.When I read those images in python and append in a python list using libraries like opencv,scipy etc the same 14400 files=2.5 to 3GB.Guess the decoding is the reason?any thoughts on this will be helpful?

Comment: The use-case is missing here! Most things have been said in Demosthenes' answer. Often people decode one and store these preprocessed images using HDF5 (for later reading). Of course this is only recommended if multiple reads are used in general (as in Machine-learning).

Answer (score 1):

You are exactly right, JPEG images are compressed (this is even a lossy compression, PNG would be a format with lossless compression), and JPEG files are much smaller than the data in uncompressed form.

When you load the images to memory, they are in uncompressed form, and having several GB of data with 14400 images is not surprising.

Basically, my advice is don't do that. Load them one at a time (or in batches), process them, then load the next images. If you load everything to memory beforehand, there will be a point when you run out of memory.

I'm doing a lot of image processing, and I have trouble imagining a case where it is necessary to have that many images loaded at once.

Comment: Great thank you for your reply.My doubt is PNGs on the other hand when loaded in memory takes less size than the JPGS.But PNGs are loseless,so am assuming it is the original size.so can 14400JPGS > 14400PNGS?? or am i missing something here??

Comment: No, PNGs will take (in general, depends on the images) more disk space. In memory, it makes no difference.

Comment: Great thank you for your answer.I did upvote as well